# Fluent NHibernate: Query a many to many relation

Tags: c#, linq, fluent-nhibernate

I have these two objects

```
public class Product {
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual IEnumerable<Store> Stores { get; set; }
}

public class Store {
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

And Fluent NHibernate creates three tables for me, one for products, on for stores and one for the relation between them.

How can I write a query that fetches all stores that's NOT related to a certain product?

In the store repository, I could do something like:

```
return GetAll().Where(x => !x.Products.Any(y => y.Id == productId));
```

... but that don't seem very efficient.

I have tried with the following line:

```
return Session.QueryOver<Store>().Where(x => !x.Products.Any(y => y.Id == productId)).List();
```

... but it almost seems like FH can't query over properties that is not a part of the queried object (the product id is not in the Company table etc).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
return Session.QueryOver<Store>().Where(x => x.Products.Where(y => y.Id == productId).Count() == 0).List();
```

Comment: I receive the error "Unrecognised method call in epression x.Products.Where(y => (y.Id == value(Temp.Persistence.Repositories.StoreRepository+<>c__D‌​isplayClass0).productId)).Count()". The error is similar to the one I get when using my second suggestion.

Comment: what version of nhibernate are you using?

Comment: try this insetd: return Session.Query<Store>().Where(x => x.Products.Where(y => y.Id == productId).Count() == 0).List(); with out QueryOver

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution, imagine you have a comboBox where you select a product and you want a list with the Stores where you cannot find that product, the solution would be the below:

```
Product product = session.Query<Product>()
                    .Where(x => x.Id == ((Product)comboBoxProduct.SelectedItem).Id)
                    .SingleOrDefault();

IList<Store> stores = session.QueryOver<Store>()
                    .Right.JoinQueryOver<Product>(x => x.ProductsInStores)
                    .Where(y => y.Id != product.Id)
                    .List<Store>();
```

Note: "ProductsInStores" would be the third class that connects "Product" and "Store"

You should also declare the name of this third class in the Maps of Product and Store.

In Product mapping you should have:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Stores)
            .Cascade.All()
            .Table("ProductsInStores");
```

In Store mapping you should have:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.Products)
            .Cascade.All()
            .Inverse()
            .Table("ProductsInStores");
```

Comment: *"ProductsInStores" would be the third class that connects "Product" and "Store"* OP expressly states this class is not in the class model.

Comment: It's not in the class model, but it is generated automatically by the NHibernate, a Many-to-Many relationship always needs a middle class. 
By the way, he should declare the name of this class when defining the many-to-many relation in the model of Product and Stores.